# Problem with local uploads to ASP.net website via CMS

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, hosting

I have a website built by ASP.net and have the admin web interface (mysite.com/cms) through which I manage the website content and upload local files from my computer normally. Since we migrated to another host, this feature stopped working and after I checked with the site developer he directed me to check the FTP permissions with the host, knowing that I can upload files using the FTP normally but this does not give me all the CMS page features. I returned to the host and he rest all the users permissions and I waited for some time for action to reflect but still nothing changed! I'm lost here and don't know what else could be the root cause for this problem since I have no experience in this field. May be worth mentioning that as a workaround we set the CMS to accept attachments or files as hyperlinks instead (to upload it via FTP and then insert the link (file path) in the CMS).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that uploading files to my website via the CMS web interface is not working after migrating to a new host, what may be the reason for such problem?